# How to pause interval and wait for function response, and run it again

Tags: javascript

As you can see here, I have a small function which will force player to go to specific coordinates. Basically as a function parameter, I set array of coordinates I want the player to go to. As you can see in example below, whenever it hits else, it means that player stays on the specific coordinates. And it adds +1 to index, so it will get the second coordinates. I'm trying to run a function in "else" tag and if the function returns true I want to run the code which is on "else" tag right now. How can I achieve that? :P

```js
var player = {
    x: 21,
    y: 24
}

function goCoords(data) {
    var index = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        if (index < data.length) {
            var coords = data[index];
            if (!(Math.abs(player.x - coords.x) <= 0 && Math.abs(player.y - coords.y) <= 0)) {
                //go(coords.x, coords.y); It will trying to go to these coords
            } else {
                //If on coords, run a function, and wait for return true
                //And run the code below again
                if (index < coords.length) {
                    index++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            clearInterval(i);
        }
    }, 150);
}

goCoords([{ x: 21, y: 24 }, { x: 21, y: 29 }]);
```

Comment: You have `var coords = data[index];` What do you think `if (index < coords.length)` will be for `var index = 0`?

Comment: My bad, updated

Answer (score 0):

Set `ttl` to the amount you want to run the same code.

```
async function goCoords(data) {
  // ...
  else {
    await recursiveFunction(...)
  }
}

async recursiveFunction(..., ttl = 2) {
  if (ttl < 1) {
    return
  }
  let result = await theFunctionThatMayReturnTrue()
  if (result) {
    // code to be executed n times (n = ttl)
    await recursiveFunction(..., --ttl)
}
```